# Why do krakens have different numbers of legs across generations?

Tags: ruby-gillman-teenage-kraken

In *Ruby Gillman: Teenage Kraken*, the titular character has three legs in her kraken form, whereas her mother has four and her grandmother has five or six. Needless to say, this is rather different from most species, where people tend to have the same number of legs as their parents.

Why does the number of legs that a kraken has seem to decrease over the generations?

Comment: Probably because animating 6 or 8 legs for an entire film is more difficult and time-consuming for the graphics people

Comment: Perhaps they develop additional legs as they age.  It works that way with humans and chins.  ;)

Comment: And, of course, kraken and merpeople are both fictional, so they are not obligated to conform to any expectations that have to do with "most species" (or even *any* real species).  You would need a sample size >1 for each generation to draw any sort of (even half-baked) generalizations about the number of legs per generation.

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm - It's an animated movie, so character design almost always is a carefully considered decision. If they decided to have each generation of the kraken family shown have one leg fewer, there is certainly some symbolic or in-universe reason for it. For instance, I read that the characters' movements in their more humanoid form were made to resemble those of an octopus to give them a more marine feel.

Comment: Well, since the film apparently didn't address it directly, you're limited to either an explanation in an official novelization, or some sort of Voice of God statement by the creator(s) addressing it.  Short of that, you're just asking people to speculate, and framing the question as though it has to make some sort of logical, real world sense is silly, because it *is* an animated movie, about a fictional world.  The only rules it owes any allegiance to are its own.   Maybe "more legs" is just a convenient way to show age that doesn't rely on grey hair or wrinkles.

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm - Yes, like many questions on this site, answering this question might require consulting secondary sources. Perhaps you have not spent much time here, because we do not restrict ourselves to what is shown in the work. We have even gotten good answers when no public information existed by reaching out to people associated with the work.

Comment: "*That Harryhausen used in-camera tricks rather than elaborate digital post-production makes all the difference. Audiences are every bit as likely to bemoan the fate of the Godzilla-like space lizard in 1957’s “20 Million Miles to Earth” as they are Jackson’s computerized Kong. **In the case of “It Came From Beneath the Sea,” Harryhausen recalls, “The budget was so low that I found that if I had an octopus, two less tentacles to animate would save some money on the special effects … so I cut off two tentacles and actually we had a sextapus.”***" - Not about this specific film, but y'know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The film's director, Kirk DeMicco confirmed in [an interview with Deadline](https://deadline.com/2023/06/ruby-gillman-teenage-kraken-interviews-dreamworks-animation-1235414795/) that krakens grow more tentacles as they age.

> Now, just to be clear about Ruby and her family: Ruby has two arms and
> three leg tentacles, as a kraken. Her mother has four, and grandma has
> five, though Pearl says it’s six.
>
> **Apparently kraken grow more tentacles as they grow older.**
>
> “Who even knows how old grandmama is? You know, she’s maybe hundreds
> of years old. We haven’t talked about that,” DeMicco laughs.
>
> <sup><sub>[‘Ruby Gillman, Teenage Kraken’ Is A Superhero, A Princess & A First
> For DreamWorks Animation – “The Story Really Is Hers”](https://deadline.com/2023/06/ruby-gillman-teenage-kraken-interviews-dreamworks-animation-1235414795/)</sub></sup>

Comment: You mean, GrandmaMA.

Comment: @Adamant - https://dreamworks.fandom.com/wiki/Grandmamah it's levi-osa, not levio-sa